# the removeEventListener is not Working and it's not anonymous

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

so I have a function that submits a post and it's called after the **onAuthStateChanged**(firebase) I want to remove it and add it again whenever a user logs in but it's not removed and I am not getting any error

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {if (user) {
// User is signed in.
// creating posts
posts = db.collection("posts");
const { serverTimestamp } = firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
console.log(serverTimestamp)
const submitPost = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  let LastId = posts.doc("id");
  let id;
  LastId.get().then((doc) => {
    id = doc.data().lastPost;
    id++;
    id = id.toString();

    const post = {
      uid: user.uid,
      content: a.preview.innerHTML,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
      id: Number(id),
    };
    console.log(post.uid);
    posts.doc(id).set(post).then(closeMD()); // puted this line here instead of outside "then" because i need the id
    LastId.update({ lastPost: Number(id) });
  });
};

submit.addEventListener("click", submitPost);
submit.removeEventListener("click" , submitPost)}
```

**EDIT**

I found that the `onAuthStateChanged` is an `observer` and I didn't really understand how to work with it, I have read the documentation and saw a video by firebase but I still didn't understand how to work with it

Comment: It looks like you're removing the listener as soon as you add it..?

Comment: yes because the `user` is changed and as you see I am using it in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to deal with it but I found a solution
I just cloned the old button and replaced it with the cloned one just like this :

```js
    const submit = document.getElementById("submitPost");
       const newSubmit = submit.cloneNode(true);
    submit.parentNode.replaceChild(newSubmit , submit)
    newSubmit.addEventListener("click", submitPost);
```

and I still want to understand how this `observal` works